# csproj file won't load how can I find out why

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a .csproj file that I merged another developers changes into, apparently incorrectly.  It's now saying (load failed) The project file cannot be loaded.

There's no information on what it doesn't like though.  Where can I find out the errors that Visual Studio sees when it tries to load my project?

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

Pretty obvious, I should have seen it earlier.  I did a Reload Project and it showed me a message box with the problem.

The messagebox error message was something like:

The project file

c:\dev\mypath\blah\blah\MyProject.csproj

has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer.

What was really odd was that the the path that messagebox complained about didn't seem to exist in any .csproj files, .sln files, etc.  None of the places I would expect it to be.  I found that it was in the MySolution.suo file.  I deleted that file and it loaded correctly the next time.  Go figure.

Comment: You always have option to delete

Comment: I don't think I'd want to delete my .csproj file, how would you suggest that I recover it, from source control?

Comment: I was talking about your post(question)

Comment: Since it turned out the problem was in the .suo file I think I'll leave it.  That was most unexpected to me.  It might be useful for someone else.